# Remove "If you're having trouble entering your password..." message on macOS

Tags: macos, users

When I turn on my MacBook Pro, I'm greeted with the familiar user list. However, there's a message at the bottom of my screen, apart from the users:

> "If you're having a problem entering your password, press and hold the power button on your Mac to shut it down. Then press it again to start up in the Recovery OS."

Since I'm the only one who uses the laptop, I have no need for this message. Is there some way to remove it, either through a Terminal command or a third-party app?

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen that message. Exactly which model of MacBook Pro are you using? Exactly which version of macOS? What settings are you using in `System Preferences > Users & Groups > Login Options` ? (maybe post a screenshot of the Login Options pane)

Comment: @Spiff I'm using a 15" 2016 MacBook Pro. [Here](http://i.imgur.com/JBnNdGs.png) is the Login Options screenshot as per your request. :)

Comment: I don't get that message on a 15" 2013 MacBook Pro running macOS Sierra 10.12.3, with Login Options configured the same. I suspect this is something specific to the the Touch Bar MBPs.

Comment: @Spiff Are you logging into the MBP on initial startup or via the Login Window ("switching users")? I see it only on the former and never the latter.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to **FileVault**. Based on some Googling, I suggest doing an NVRAM reset to see if it clears the message.

Comment: Would you be able to link to said reference?  Also elaborate on how to perform an NVRAM reset?